# Why is it best practice to include the dependencies' dependencies in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, dependencies, requirements.txt

I appreciate that in many circumstances it is important to explicitly state what dependency versions we are working with and that this thus applies to the nested dependencies as well.

However, it becomes very messy when we decide to remove a dependency and need to use something like pideptree to find out if it had any dependencies of its own which we also installed and additionally make sure that these nested dependencies are not being used by our other first-level dependencies.

Assuming we don't need to freeze our dependency versions what is the advantage of including the nested dependencies rather than just letting pip take care of it for us?

Answer (score 5):

People actually don't do that. `requirements.txt` really should list your dependencies without nested dependencies. Pinned dependencies are usually put in another file:

```
pip freeze > requirements-freeze.txt
```

If people pin dependencies in `requirements.txt` that's not exactly a bug but not the best practice for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you are right. If you have tried `pipenv`, you will find it is the thing what you want.

The reason why people write all nested dependencies in `requirements.txt` is just because `pip freeze > requirements.txt` will list all installed packages.

And `pipenv` use a better way to manage dependencies which likes `npm` or `yarn` so you can easily delete all nested dependencies for a top module.

But it is still reasonable to list all nested dependencies. A case I met before, that is a third-party A rely on another third-party B. And the dependency of B in A is `B>=4.10.0`. But in `B==4.12.0`, some packages were migrated from one module to another module. As the importation broke so that the whole lib A broke too.

Comment: "you will find it is the thing what you want". That's not what I found

Comment: @JoelB Yes, this is an old story. Now it is not what you want any more. What a sad story.